# Unable to create payment intent

Tags: stripe-payments, magento2

I'm trying to purchase using Stripe payment method. Now the module is working properly in our staging environment but when I try to purchase using stripe in my localhost I'm getting an error of `Unable to create payment intent` now there are no explanation in stripe documentation. How can I fix this? In the dev console it only returns a 400 error with message as mentioned.

[image]

This is from the Stripe library I used in Magento 2. As you can see at the bottom most part of the image it throws an error

Comment: Could you provide some example of the code where this error is being raised? Right now there's not much to go on as that error is not indicative of any underlying issue.

Comment: @taintedzodiac updated my question

Comment: Thanks @MadzQuestioning -- I'd suggest doing some local logging in your logic to see which pieces of code are/aren't running. Since you're returning an error based on `if (!this->paymentIntent)`, the next step would be to find out where in your earlier code things break down. Really what we'd want to get to here is what specific line of your code is throwing the real issue that underlies why `$this->paymentIntent` doesn't get created.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will need to find out that how to set up the payment method on local environment. Every payment method will not have the same setting on local with a live sever.
If they don't have any resolution in their document, you will have to reach out their phone or email them to get support.
I have this experience when i work with GMO and Amazon payment gateway.